# Margin options in Pdf with Rotativa Mvc

Tags: c#, pdf, model-view-controller, rotativa

I have been reading that to put or remove the margins of a PDF the following line is used:

```
PageMargins = new Rotativa.Core.Options.Margins(0,0,0,0)
```

But, when I enter them I get the following:

[image]

```
'ViewAsPDF' does not contain a definition for 'PageMargins'
```

Any solution?

This is the complete code:

```
return new ViewAsPdf("Pdf48", c.cargarDatosPDF(solicitud))
                    {
                        CustomSwitches = "--header-html " + _headerUrl + " --header-spacing 0 " +
                                 "--footer-html " + _footerUrl + " --footer-spacing 0",
                       PageMargins = new Rotativa.Core.Options.Margins(0,0,0,0)                
                    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

```
return new PartialViewAsPdf("Pdf48", c.cargarDatosPDF(solicitud))
                    {
                        RotativaOptions = new Rotativa.Core.DriverOptions
                        {
                            CustomSwitches = "--header-html " + _headerUrl + " --header-spacing 0 " +
                                "--footer-html " + _footerUrl + " --footer-spacing 0",
                            PageMargins = new Rotativa.Core.Options.Margins(0, 0, 0, 0)
                        }
                };
```

Answer (score -1):

This should help.

var pdfdoc= new Rotativa.ViewAsPdf(){

```
                 PageHeight=30.00,
                 PageWidth=30.00,
                 PageMargins=new Rotativa.Options.Margins(0,0,0,0)
                 
                
             };
```

Comment: This is the same code that isn't working for the OP.